# Verilog 4x16 Decoder outputs wrong data

Tags: verilog, decoder, icarus

I have implemented a 4x16 Decoder using Verilog along with it's test. For each case the decoder should output a 16-bit digit with only one of the bits high. I can't manage to get all the desired outputs when I run the program. Here is the code for the Decoder and test, and the output at the console:

4x16 Decoder:

```
module Decoder4x16 (input [3:0] select, input enable, output reg [16:0] out);

always @(select, enable)
begin

    if(enable == 1'b0)
        out = 16'b0000000000000000;
    else if(enable == 1'b1)
        if(select == 4'b0000)
            out <= 16'b0000000000000001;
        else if(select == 4'b0001)
            out <= 16'b0000000000000010;
        else if(select == 4'b0010)
            out <= 16'b0000000000000100;
        else if(select == 4'b0011)
            out <= 16'b0000000000001000;
        else if(select == 4'b0100)
            out <= 16'b0000000000010000;
        else if(select == 4'b0101)
            out <= 16'b0000000000100000;
        else if(select == 4'b0110)
            out <= 16'b0000000001000000;
        else if(select == 4'b0111)
            out <= 16'b0000000010000000;
        else if(select == 4'b1000)
            out <= 16'b0000000100000000;
        else if(select == 4'b1001)
            out <= 16'b0000001000000000;
        else if(select == 4'b1010)
            out <= 16'b0000010000000000;
        else if(select == 4'b1011)
            out <= 16'b0000100000000000;
        else if(select == 4'b1100)
            out <= 16'b0001000000000000;
        else if(select == 4'b1101)
            out <= 16'b0010000000000000;
        else if(select == 4'b111)
            out <= 16'b0100000000000000;
        else if(select == 4'b1111)
            out <= 16'b1000000000000000;
    end

endmodule
```

Test:

```
module Decoder4x16_test;

reg [3:0] select;
reg enable;
wire [16:0] out;

parameter sim_time = 2800;

Decoder4x16 decoder(select, enable, out);
initial #sim_time $finish;
initial
begin
    select = 4'b0000;
    enable = 1'b0;

    repeat(16) #10 begin
        enable = 1'b1;
        #85 $display("select = %b \t out = %b", select, out);
        select = select + 4'b0001;
    end
end
endmodule
```

When I run the program it outputs the correct output until it reaches the test case where the input is 1101. After that the decoder outputs the wrong value that it is suppose to display. Here is the output:

```
select = 0000    out = 00000000000000001
select = 0001    out = 00000000000000010
select = 0010    out = 00000000000000100
select = 0011    out = 00000000000001000
select = 0100    out = 00000000000010000
select = 0101    out = 00000000000100000
select = 0110    out = 00000000001000000
select = 0111    out = 00000000010000000
select = 1000    out = 00000000100000000
select = 1001    out = 00000001000000000
select = 1010    out = 00000010000000000
select = 1011    out = 00000100000000000
select = 1100    out = 00001000000000000
select = 1101    out = 00010000000000000
select = 1110    out = 00010000000000000
select = 1111    out = 01000000000000000
```

Comment: You have typo'ed a condition: `else if(select == 4'b111)` should be `else if(select == 4'b1110)`

Answer (score 4):

Here, `out` is a `reg` that means it **holds** a value that is assigned to it. There is no `else if` condition for `select=4'b1110`. So, `out` **holds** or **retains** its **previous value** which was from `select=4'b1101`. That is, `out` holds value `00010000000000000` which is displayed.

So, **add** an `else if` condition for `select=4'b1110` and the code works fine.

```
  else if(select == 4'b1110)
            out <= 16'b0100000000000000;
```

Moreover, a decoder is **purely combinational circuit**. While creating any  combinational logic, the use of **blocking assignments**(`=`) is preferred. So, use the following syntax.

```
  else if(select == 4'b1110)
            out = 16'b0100000000000000; // blocking
```

One more thing just to elaborate, use `always@(*)` instead of manual **sensitivity list**. This will help reducing confusion of sensitivity lists.

Answer (score 4):

Try this simple code,

```
module Decoder4x16 (input [3:0] select, 
                    input enable, 
                    output wire [16:0] out);

assign out = {17{enable}} & (1'b1 << select);

endmodule
```

Synthesized in ISE too.

Comment: Can you explain `assign out = {17{enable}} & (1'b1 << select);` a bit more?

Comment: 1 is shifted to decimal position given by select input.